# Strongly typing the value parameter of the render method of the Controller in React hook form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

With react hook form the `Controller#render` method is passed a `value` parameter which contains the current control value. It is typed as `any`, is it possible to strongly type this, for example if the component managed by the controller is to render a `string` the value argument to the `render` method should be typed as `string` in the value parameter. Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/blissful-sinoussi-92i93?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, register } = useForm<Person>({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Smith"
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: Person) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="firstName" ref={register} />
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="lastName"
        // *************************************
        // ====> value is typed as `any`, how to type it as the bound enity, i.e. string from Person.lastName?
        // *************************************
        render={({ onChange, name, value }) => (
          <input
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      />

      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I suppose you should specify it here: `({ onChange, name, value } : { onChange: () => void, name: string, value: string }) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution v7**

Since v7, RHF has a much better TypeScript support compared to v6. Hence, for example, the breaking changes regarding the `register` method. If possible, update to this version.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - TS Value]

**Solution v6**

If you need to use v6 there is this little [package](https://github.com/react-hook-form/strictly-typed) provided by RHF, which will make `Controller` components more type-safe.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - TS Value v6]

Answer (score 0):

Running RHF 7.18.0 and Typescript 4.4.4.
the `Controller` definition seems to have changed. Can not find a way to type Contoller's `value` and `defaultValue`.
I'm trying to create a generic `Select` field as below, but when passing the generic T as the second type of Contoller, ESLint complains.

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Select, { SelectProps } from "@mui/material/Select";
import { Control, Controller, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

type UnBox<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;

export interface IOptions<T> {
  value: T;
  displayedLabel: string;
}

type ISelectFieldProps<T extends Array<string | number> | string | number> =
  SelectProps<T> & {
    name: string;
    control: Control;
    options: Array<IOptions<T extends Array<string | number> ? UnBox<T> : T>>;
    optionsAsCheckBox?: boolean;
  };

const SelectField = <T extends Array<string | number> | string | number>({
  name,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  label,
  options,
  optionsAsCheckBox = false,
  ...rest
}: ISelectFieldProps<T>): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Controller<FieldValues, T>  <--error here. Changing T to any fixed, but then value and defaultValue are any and not typeof T...
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
        <Box>
          <InputLabel id={name}>{label}</InputLabel>
          <Select
            label={label}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            {...rest}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {optionsAsCheckBox && (
                  <Checkbox checked={value.indexOf(option.value) > -1} />
                )}
                <ListItemText primary={option.displayedLabel} />{" "}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Box>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default SelectField;
```

**example to call it**

```
<SelectField<Array<string>>
        name="ton"
        multiple
        control={control}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
        defaultValue={[]}
        label="Ton"
        options={[
          {
            value: "A",
            displayedLabel: "AAAA",
          },
          {
            value: "B",
            displayedLabel: "BBBB",
          },
          {
            value: "C",
            displayedLabel: "CCCCC",
          },
        ]}
      />
```

[image: Error]